# unable to set data in excel using apache POI in data driven framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, data-driven

I was unable to set data in excel using poi i do have an set data reuse method in my excel util class getting an null pointer exception initially it written data into excel now its showing null pointer.could anyone help me here it is setdata code

```
public String setCellData(String xlfile,String xlsheet,int rownum,int colnum,String data) throws IOException
{
    fi=new FileInputStream(xlfile);
    wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
    ws=wb.getSheet(xlsheet);
    row=ws.createRow(rownum);
    cell=row.getCell(colnum,Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
    if(cell==null) {
    cell=row.createCell(colnum);
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    }else {
        cell.setCellValue(data);
    }
    fo=new FileOutputStream(xlfile);
    wb.write(fo);       
    wb.close();
    fi.close();
    fo.close();
    return data;
}
```

it's showing NULLPOINTER exception IN THIS LINE
cell=row.getCell(colnum,Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

Comment: If NPE occurs in that code line, then `row` must be `null`. Do `row=ws.getRow(rownum); if (row == null) row = ws.createRow(rownum);`

Comment: sorry i forget to set code properly i have tried above on e also its not showing nullpointer  exception  but is saw in excel data is not setting it show blank.

Comment: So the code you are showing is not the code which causes the problem? And the problem also is not a NPE as told in the question but something else what not was told in the question? Sorry but then no answer is possible. Please edit your question so it explains the problem and shows the code which causes the problem.

Comment: Here the explanation is edited